# boost asio async_receive_from() missing udp frames data retrieval when frames sent consecutive

Tags: c++, boost-asio

The MVCE below simplified from real codebase shows the same issue.

The server continuously sends a "burst" of 5 UDP frames filled with 150 bytes of value 0xA5 with small or no delay in between. A pause of 1 second is made.

The client use the **boost::asio** **async_receive_from()** function in parallel of a 1 second timer.
The client works relatively well except when the delay between the UDP frames is "too" small. It seems that the correct size ( here 150 bytes ) is retrieved but the buffer/vector seems not to be updated.

- 5 x 150 bytes of UDP frames does not seem much.
- Wireshark DOES see the complete and correct frames sent.
- If I use a synchronous boost asio socket synchronous receive_from() I meet no issues

I tried maybe half a dozen times to dive into boost asio without much success in finding a single truth or rationale. Same posts on SO show very different code so that it is difficult to transpose them to the present code

Here are the code
**client** (client_with_timer.cc)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
void asyncReadHandler( const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytesTransferred );
void timeoutHandler( const boost::system::error_code& error, bool* ptime_out );

size_t ReceivedDataSize;
std::string ReadError;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    io_service io;

    ip::udp::socket socket(io, ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 1620));

    size_t num = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned char> vec(1500);

        ip::udp::endpoint from;

        socket.async_receive_from(
                        boost::asio::buffer( vec ),
                        from,
                        boost::bind(
                                asyncReadHandler,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred ) );

        bool timeout = false;
        ReceivedDataSize = 0;
        ReadError = "";

        // Creating and starting timer (by registering timeout handler)
        deadline_timer timer( io, boost::posix_time::seconds( 1 ) );
        timer.async_wait(
            boost::bind( timeoutHandler, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &timeout ) );

        // Resetting IO service instance
        io.reset();

        while(io.run_one())
        {
            if ( timeout ) {
                socket.cancel();
                timer.cancel();
                //Leave the io run_one loop
                break;
            }
            else if ( (0 != ReceivedDataSize ) || (!ReadError.empty())) {
                timer.cancel();
                socket.cancel();
                std::cout << "Received n°" <<  num++ << ": " << ReceivedDataSize << "\r" << std::flush;

                if (0 != ReceivedDataSize )
                    vec.resize(ReceivedDataSize);

                if (!ReadError.empty())
                    std::cout << "Error: " << ReadError << std::endl;

                bool result = true;
                for ( auto x : vec )
                    if ( 0xA5 != x ) { result = false; break; }

                if ( false == result ) {
                    std::cout << std::endl << "Bad reception" << std::endl << std::hex;
                    for ( auto x : vec )
                        std::cout << (int)x << " ";

                    std::cout << std::dec << "\n";
                }
                //Leave the io run_one loop
                break;
            }
            else {
                //What shall I do here ???
                //another potential io.reset () did not bring much
            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void asyncReadHandler( const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytesTransferred )
{
    // If read canceled, simply returning...
    if( error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted ) return;

    ReceivedDataSize = 0;

    // If no error
    if( !error ) {
        ReceivedDataSize = bytesTransferred;
    }
    else {
        ReadError = error.message();
    }
}

void timeoutHandler( const boost::system::error_code& error, bool* ptime_out )
{
    // If timer canceled, simply returning...
    if( error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted ) return;

    // Setting timeout flag
    *ptime_out = true;
}
```

Here is the **server** (server.cc) so that you do not have to roll your own

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace boost::asio;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    io_service io;

    ip::udp::socket socket(io, ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 0));

    std::vector<char> vec(150,0xA5);
#if 1
    int separator = 1 * 1000;
#else
    int separator = 0;
#endif

    while (true)
    {
        socket.send_to(buffer(vec), ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 1620));
        if ( separator ) usleep(separator);
        socket.send_to(buffer(vec), ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 1620));
        if ( separator ) usleep(separator);
        socket.send_to(buffer(vec), ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 1620));
        if ( separator ) usleep(separator);
        socket.send_to(buffer(vec), ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 1620));
        if ( separator ) usleep(separator);
        socket.send_to(buffer(vec), ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 1620));

        usleep(1000*1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled both with the naive commands below:

*g++ client_with_timer.cc -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -o client_with_timer -lboost_system*

*g++ server.cc -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -o server -lboost_system*

It produces output like below when delay is too small

```
nils@localhost ASIO_C]$ ./client_with_timer 
Received n°21: 150
Bad reception
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Received n°148: 150
Bad reception
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Received n°166: 150
Bad reception
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Received n°194: 150
```

How to correct the client code to avoid missed frames ?
Any hint for a better understanding of boost asio rationale is welcome

Comment: What are OS on client and server? What is the version of boost.asio you use?

Comment: @Oleg Andriyanov : Yes sorry. Problem was seen on RHEL 7 64 bits  and I reproduced it on  CentOS 7 64 bits both with boost 1.53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your code are data races.
If timer is expired (timeout occures) before read operation is completed below code is executed:

```
if ( timeout ) {
                socket.cancel();
                timer.cancel();
                //Leave the io run_one loop
                break; // [1]
            }
```

you are breaking from while loop, `socket.cancel()` cancels asynchronus read operation, its handler with `operation_aborted` error is queued and waits for processing in event loop. Because you jumped from while loop, `run_one` is not invoked, and this handler is still in queue.

`io_service.reset()` doesn't clear queue. Handler for aborted operation is still there. And waits to be invoked. `reset()` only sets `stopped` flag of `io_service` to `false`, then handlers can be processed by calls `run_one`, `one` .. methods, you are using `reset` to restore processing handlers from queue.

So we have unprocessed handler in queue, in main while loop new vector `vec` is created, all its elements are initialized to 0. `async_receive_from` started (it is reading into `vec` and set `ReceivedDataSize` in its handler), then `reset` is called, `run_one` can process handler and invokes handler for aborted operation! and you are testing `ReceivedDataSize` and `vec` for aborted operation... but you should do it for the last started async operation.

I would rewrite clause with timeout to:

```
if ( timeout ) {
                socket.cancel();
                timer.cancel();
} // no break
```

after removing break we guarantee that aborted operation is processed by `run_one` and there is no outstanding handler to be invoked when new async operation is started.
After this modifcation I have not seen `bad reception` while testing your code.

**EDIT**

Regarding your comment, yes the other `break` statement should also be removed from the code.

Output of the program is unpredictable because you are starting async operations which takes reference to local variable (`vec` is modified by `async_receive_from`), handler is queued, local variable is destroyed and later the handler is called from io_service while `vec` has been already destroyed.

You can test the code below, and see what happens:

```
  boost::asio::io_context io; // alias on io_service

  boost::asio::system_timer t1{io};
  t1.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  boost::asio::system_timer t2{io};
  t2.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  boost::asio::system_timer t3{io};
  t3.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  t1.async_wait ([](const boost::system::error_code& ec){ cout << "[1]" << endl;});
  t2.async_wait ([](const boost::system::error_code& ec){ cout << "[2]" << endl;});
  t3.async_wait ([](const boost::system::error_code& ec){ cout << "[3]" << endl;});
  // 3 handlers are queueud
  cout << "num of handlers executed " << io.run_one() << endl; // wait for handler, print 1
  io.reset(); // RESET is called
  cout << "num of handlers executed " << io.run_one() << endl; // wait for handler, print 1
  io.reset(); // RESET is called
  cout << "num of handlers executed " << io.run_one() << endl; // wait for handler, print 1
  cout << "executed: " <<                io.poll_one() << endl; // call handler if any ready, print 0
```

we are calling `io_service::reset` but all handlers are executed. After removing `break`s from your code, you ensure that all handlers will be performed, and it guarantees that the local data are valid when these handlers are called.

Comment: I confirm that removing the break inside the timeout test makes the bug disappear from the MVCE on RHEL7 and CentOS 7 ( GCC 4.8.5 for both ) + disappear also from the real (complete) code. Many thanks for this and also for your explanation that seems clearer than all (the few) documentation I read. I still don't get all the story but with this new knowledge I will go again to further documentation reading. For the time being I just wonder about the validity of the  second "break" of the reception test if the "break" of the timeout test was invalid !?